# whats the best way to verify forms without clearing them?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have some html forms that I verify completeness with php. The issue I have is that when one required form is not filled, the filled forms are cleared.

The HTML

```
<p>Email: <span class="required">* <?php echo $EmailErr;?></span><input type="text" name="Email" placeholder="Email" /></p>
<p>Comments: =input type="text" name="Comments" maxlength="75" placeholder="Comments"/></p>
```

This is the PHP

```
 if (empty($_POST["Email"])) {
   $EmailErr = "";
   } else {
   $Email = validateEmail($_POST["Email"]);
   }        

   if (empty($_POST["Comments"])) {
   $Comments = "";
   } else {
   $Comments = test_input($_POST["Comments"]);
   }
```

The question remains, how do I prevent the other forms from being cleared upon submission?

Comment: you prevent them being cleared, you repopulate the form with the filled in values `value=$_POST['what ever']`

Comment: forms or fields? they are very different.

Answer (score 1):

You should do a client side validation in order to retain the values on your form.

That being said you should still have server validation.

There is different way to do it, using javascript/jquery or even simply adding `required` attribute to your tag, for example:

```
<input type="text" name="Email" placeholder="Email" required/>
```

for javascript:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

for jquery , here is a good plugin:

http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: I validate the forms through functions to clean the input, as they are inserted into an sql database.

Comment: you can still do this on the server once the client validate it

Comment: you can have the server redisplay the value using post or session array but its messy

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>
    Email: <span class="required">*<?php echo $EmailErr; ?></span>
    <input type="text" name="Email" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo!empty($_POST['Email']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['Email']) : '' ?>"/>
</p>
<p>
    Comments: <textarea name="Comments" maxlength="75" placeholder="Comments"><?php echo!empty($_POST['Comments']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['Comments']) : '' ?></textarea>
</p>
```